# How do I connect a post to list of posts

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Im trying to make a simple blog with php. What I'm doing is to link a post to lists of post on the blog. For example, just like this.

[Example of a posts list and a post viewer i planned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0mcW.png)

So there's two different parts of source. First of all, this source shows the lists of posts existing on the blog.

```
<?php

     $host = 'localhost';
     $user = 'root';
     $password = 'root';
     $db = 'urls';
     $port = 8889;


     $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db, $port);

     if (!$conn) {
         die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
     }

     $sql = "SELECT id, title, url, votes FROM link ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
         // output data of each row
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
             echo '
                      <li class="list-group-item">
                          <span class="badge">' . $row['votes'] . '</span>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Like</button>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Hate</button>
                          <a href="#" onClick="location.href='post_link.php'" >' . $row['title'] . '</a>
                      </li>';
         }
     } else {
         echo "0 results";
     }

     mysqli_close($conn);

 ?>
```

I linked the title of a post to another php file, but it seems like its not working.

```
 <a href="#" onClick="location.href='post_link.php'" >' . $row['title'] . '</a>
                      </li>';
```

And this source is the page where i show specific details of a post.

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><? echo $row['title'] ?></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <? echo $row['url']?>
      <button type="button" class="btn ban-info">Like</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn ban-danger">Hate</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

However, its not working as well. So how can i solve this problem?

Comment: You have an `>` in the middle of your link. Why? You close the tag at the end, not in the middle.

Comment: On a tags you can set the url in the href without needing to set an onclick attribute like this: 

    <a href="/post_link.php" >' . $row['title'] . '</a>

Comment: When you say "it seems like it's not working" are you saying that it doesn't take you to the new page or what? Could you please explain a little better what's not working instead of just saying that it's not working?

Comment: @Sloganho it doesn't take me to the new page. Sorry for not specifying the problem.

Comment: For debugging, try setting this as your a tag: <a href="https://www.google.com" >' . $row['title'] . '</a> just to make sure you are going to google. If you are going to google, I would change it back to <a href="/post_link.php" >' . $row['title'] . '</a> and then check if you can get to /post_link.php manually by just putting the whole url into the browser you're testing on. If you can't get to /post_link.php then I would look into the file structure of your project to find out how to get to /post_link.php

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like this `<a href="www.site.com/post_link.php/$row['title']">Text</a>`

Comment: Please edit your post and explain why this would work.